# C++ // pass a Boost::array to Boost::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I want to pass a "boost::array" to "booth::thread" job.

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
boost::array<BYTE,256> readBuffer;
thread gojob(&thread_job, readBuffer.data() );
```

How to pass it ?

```
void serial::thread_job(BYTE *received) {

}
```

I wrote this.. but Compile gave me strange message only..
I can not understand what he is talking....

```
include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:333:36: error: cannot apply member pointer ‘((const boost::_mfi::dm<void(unsigned char*), serial>*)this)->boost::_mfi::dm<void(unsigned char*), serial>::f_’ to ‘* boost::get_pointer<unsigned char>(((unsigned char*)u))’, which is of non-class type ‘unsigned char’
```

Comment: [Looks like `boost::array::data()` is `const`, for one thing.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/array.html#idm45507153295488-bb). So you try to pass a `unsigned char const *` to a function expecting an `unsigned char *`. Pass this through a complicated library, and it could give some weird error, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the buffer and then work on the data(), you could do something like:

```
thread gojob(boost::bind(&serial::thread_job,this, boost::ref(readBuffer))
```

Comment: I change code like this  :  next error message is "include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:333:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘get_pointer(const boost::array<unsigned char, 256ul>&)’"        job function is ok ?   void serial::thread_job(BYTE *received)

Comment: no it is not, `serial::thread_job(BYTE* received)` now becomes `serial::thread_job(boost::array& received)`

Comment: thank you. but My ability is not enable to write next line... : (                               void serial::thread_job(boost::array& received) {
       /*  How to use/convert to Original boost::array<BYTE,256> ?? */
 BYTE Command = *(received+2);   ?

Comment: again, I need your help....                                  1) void serial::thread_job(boost::array& received)   ---------->  this make a error "error: ‘boost::array’ is not a type"                                    2)  the, I changed to "   void thread_job(boost::array<BYTE,256>& received)          "   but this also make another error -----------------------------> include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:333:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘get_pointer(const boost::array<unsigned char, 256ul>&)’

Comment: `template<typename T, typename S>
void thread_job (boost::array<T, S> & received) { //blah }`

Comment: So im in front of a compiler now and this works: 
`class foo 
{ 
private:  typedef unsigned char BYTE;
boost::array<BYTE,256> readBuffer;
void thread_job(boost::array<BYTE,256>& received);
void bar(); 
}`
`void foo::thread_job(boost::array<BYTE,256>& received) {}` and `void foo::bar() {boost::thread gojob(boost::bind(&foo::thread_job,this, boost::ref(readBuffer)));`

Comment: Thank you ! I got "Build Finished (took 6s.82ms) "  !!!   it's so complex grammer for New user of C++....    thank you. Samer